# Chrome messes with table

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

so my problem is that while the website looks ok in FireFox ([screenshot](http://i40.tinypic.com/53acdl.png)), it kinda messes with the tables in Chrome ([screenshot](http://i39.tinypic.com/347f9zl.png)).
I have validated my html and css and tried some other stuff, but I have no clue how to fix this.

HTML:

```
<div id="top" class="topbg" style="width: 100%; height: 457px;">
<table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 459px; height: 102px"></td>
        <td style="height: 102px; width: 433px;">
        <div style="clear: both;" class="toptitle"></div>
        </td>
        <td style="height: 102px; width: 545px;">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 99%; height: 105px">
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style1" style="height: 28px">
                <a href="#"><img alt="" height="18" src="flags/de.png" width="25" />&nbsp;</a>
                <a href="index-it.html"><img alt="" height="18" src="flags/it.png" width="25" />&nbsp;</a>
                <a href="index-en.html"><img alt="" height="18" src="flags/gb.png" width="25" /></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </td>
        <td style="height: 102px"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 459px; height: 243px"></td>
        <td style="height: 243px; width: 433px;"></td>
        <td style="height: 243px" colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 459px; height: 70px"></td>
        <td style="height: 70px" colspan="3"><a style="clear: both;" href="#" class="btn1">Verfügbarkeit</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.fit {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
.center {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
.bgimg {
    background-image: url(images/bg.png);
}
.topbg {
    background-image: url(images/topbg.jpg);
}
.topbg2{
    background-image: url(images/topbg2.jpg);
}
.toptitle{
    background-image: url(images/toptitle.png);
    height:110px;
    width:270px;
}

.link {
  color: #d2c13f;
  background-color: transparent ;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.link:hover {
  color: white ;
  background-color: transparent ;
}

.wrapper {
        background: #595959;
    }
    .wrapper ul {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        display: inline;
    }
    .wrapper li {
        float: left;
        padding: 0px 0px;
        border: 0px solid black;
    }
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Please provide code or a JSFiddle

Comment: Post your HTML and CSS *here*

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not contain the code relevant to the question.

Comment: please provide some code.

Comment: Sorry, now it is added.

Comment: -1 just for using tables for layout in the 21st century.

Comment: Tables? Seriously?? May I suggest paying a visit here: http://www.w3schools.com/

Comment: Aye, the best answer to this question is to rewrite your html to not use tables, and then start again from there. May not be your favourite answer, but it is the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://shouldiusetablesforlayout.com/

And now for the non-pretentious answer:
You really shouldn't use tables for layout. If you know how to style this much, it should take you very little time to learn basic CSS positioning. 
Chris Coyiers article is a good place to start:
http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

Then use `<div>` elements to make your basic page layout.

Comment: Thanks! I really didn't know that you shouldn't use tables (learned it in school that way) and I'm normally more a programmer, so before I started with this website I hardly ever informed about HTML. I'll check the article out and try to use <div> layout in the future :)